# kdeinit5 starts background konsoles with high CPU usage

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cpu, konsole

I am using KDE Neon LTS 5.12, sometimes, for some unknown reason, I can see a high CPU usage that comes from started konsoles by kdeinit5.

Every konsole has no window and uses up to 17% CPU approximately. As I do not know the reason this happens, sometimes I see one, or two, or 4 konsoles (17% * 4 = 68% CPU usage) with the same description: `konsole [kdeinit5]`.

[image: konsole [kdeinit5] problem]

It says I am the user who started these, but I do not know what do I do that makes this happen.

If I try to `[Jump to the parent process]` in the context menu, It redirects me to the obvious `kdeinit5: Running...` process.

[image: konsole [kdeinit5] problem]

I have been checking forums but did not found a solution yet.